# Can a SSAS Data Source View be pointed to a different server data source?

Tags: ssas, datasourceview

We are doing a parallel migration of our SQL Server 2005 database, cube and SSIS packages to 2008 R2.  The cube successfully migrate to 2008 R2 via the BIDS migration wizard.  However, the Data Source View is still pointing to the old server.

Do we need to delete the DSV pointing to the old server, and create a new one pointing to the new server?  Or, is there a way to change a property of the DSV so that it uses the new server's data source?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data source view has a "Data Source" property in its property pane which you can see if nothing is selected in the DSV.

And instead of changing this, you can of course just change the connection properties of teh existing data source (note that I really say "data source" here, not "data source view"!).